# Apache Flink Dev documentation?

Tags: apache-flink

I am interested in learning about how Flink works internally, but I am struggling to find documentation on the internal code (like where is a start point of a job) so I am unable to understand the codebase. Is there documentation or some walkthrough for those who want to contribute to Flink itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that if you understand how some part of Flink works, the source code is generally understandable. The initial challenge then is to have a correct understanding of the expected behavior of the code. To that end, here are some helpful resources:

The best starting point is [Stream Processing with Apache Flink](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/stream-processing-with/9781491974285/) by Fabian Hueske and Vasiliki Kalavri.

Any significant development work done on Flink in recent years has been preceded by a [Flink Improvement Proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Flink+Improvement+Proposals). These are probably the best available resource for getting a deeper understanding of specific topics and areas of the code.

The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/) has a section on "Internals" that covers some topics.

And there have been some excellent Flink Forward talks describing how some of the internals work, such as [Aljoscha Krettek's talk on the ongoing work to unify batch and streaming](https://www.ververica.com/resources/flink-forward-san-francisco-2019/towards-flink-2.0-rethinking-the-stack-and-apis-to-unify-batch-stream), [Nico Kruber's talk on the network stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scStdhz9FHc), Stefan Richter's talks on [state](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scStdhz9FHc) and [checkpointing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWQ24wERItM&list=PLDX4T_cnKjD0JeULl1X6iTn7VIkDeYX_X&index=37&t=0s), [Piotr Nowojski's talk on two phase commit sinks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rh7wdvZXTOo&list=PLDX4T_cnKjD0JeULl1X6iTn7VIkDeYX_X&index=20&t=0s), and [Addison Higham's talk on operators](https://www.ververica.com/resources/flink-forward-san-francisco-2019/becoming-a-smooth-operator-a-look-at-low-level-flink-apis-and-what-they-enable),  among many others.

Comment: Navigating through the codebase seems extremely difficult given the number of files and classes present. Can you give me some core classes to read through to get an underatanding of the distributed stream processing in action? I am interesting in learning how the actual events get sent to different distributed machines for example and where in code the parallelism happens.